# How to install ns2 simulation on Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, ns2

I am trying to install ns2 simulations on ubuntu 18.04.5, But got an error.
I was followed this step https://www.absingh.com/ns2/

```
E: Unable to locate package ns2
```

Comment: If never `sudo apt-get update`, do it then `sudo apt-get install ns2`

Comment: Basic simulations: `sudo apt install ns2-examples` . .... All ~3000 simulations https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing